# How to use php redirect with header and proxy

Tags: php, redirect, proxy, header

I need to use 

`header('Location: http://someur')`

but the server this script is running from must use a proxy server to connect.

How do I use a header redirect with a proxy server?

Comment: Proxy is nothing to do with this. It's a response to the client, telling the client what URL to use.

Comment: And the client itself decides whether it wants to use a proxy or not. You cannot somehow force it.

Comment: the script which is the header using is conecting to soap api for payment , but server where is running cannot connect to internet without proxy

Comment: maybe the problem is another on error log I have AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown

Comment: How the server connects to the internet is nothing to do with the client.